# SAS: TRANSPOSE without using PROC TRANSPOSE?

Tags: sas, transpose

I have SAS data like this.

```
dog cat mice camel pigeon cow goat fish horse donkey monkey lion rat
DOG CAT MICE CAMEL PIGEON COW GOAT FISH HORSE DONKEY MONKEY LION RAT
```

Non-capital name is column names. And Capital letters are observations.

And I want to make a table like below WITHOUT using PROC TRANSPOSE function. Column names are AnimalName and LastAlpha. The LastAlpha is the last alphabet for the AnimalName observations.

```
AnimalName LastAlpha
DOG        G
CAT        T
MICE       E
CAMEL      L
PIGEON     N
COW        W
GOAT       T
FISH       H
HORSE      E
DONKEY     Y
MONEKY     Y
LION       N
RAT        T
```

I was attempting using ARRAY function to make this table, but no luck. I would appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make your example into a dataset.

```
data have;
  input (dog cat mice camel pigeon cow goat fish horse donkey monkey lion rat) ($);
cards;
DOG CAT MICE CAMEL PIGEON COW GOAT FISH HORSE DONKEY MONKEY LION RAT
;
```

Now let's make your output.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array list _character_ ;
  do i=1 to dim(list);
     AnimalName = list(i);
     LastAlpha = char(AnimalName,length(AnimalName));
     output;
  end;
  keep AnimalName LastAlpha;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.  Let me know if it's what you are looking for:

```
DATA Want;
set Have;
array x{*} _character_;
keep AnimalName LastAlpha;
do i =1 to dim(x);
AnimalName = x[i];
LastAlpha =   substr(AnimalName,length(AnimalName),1);
output;
end;
run;
```